# How to select using join on two conditions for the same column

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to achieve something like this.

```
id  tag   name
1   foo    name
1   bar    name
2   foo    name
2  foss   name
```

What I tried to do is.

```
select id, group_concat(distinct tag) as tag, group_concat(distinct name) as name
where tag = "foo" or tag = "bar" group by id;
```

to which I get,

```
id     tag       name
1    foo, bar  name
2    foo, foss name
```

But, what I want is only if tag is "foo" and "bar" for same id,then print, which is supposed to give output like this.

```
id     tag       name
1     foo, bar   name
```

I did this, as it would work in programming languages like JAVA or C++, by using AND. It results in null..

```
select id, group_concat(distinct tag) as tag, group_concat(distinct name) as name
where (tag = "foo" and tag = "bar") group by id;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want a `group by` and a `having`:

```
select id, group_concat(distinct tag) as tag,
       group_concat(distinct name) as name
from t
where tag in ('foo', 'bar')
group by id
having count(distinct tag) = 2;
```

As a note.  Any programming language that I'm familiar with would return false for `tag = 'foo' and tag = 'bar'`, because tag could have one value or the other, but not both.